# I don't have the right HBOOT version, can I still install Cyangenmod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, bootloader

I ran `adb reboot bootloader` on my HTC Sensation XE and it states that the version is `1.29.0000`

[According to the wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_pyramid) I must have version **`1.17.0006, .0008, .0011 and .0012, 1.18.0000`**?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't install a CM Rom without having the correct bootloader. You will brick your device or end up bootlooping it.

Download and flash correct HBOOT, then continue with your choice of Rom.

---

as per your wiki link

***`"Pay close attention to the HBOOT revision as newer updates break the tool's ability to work properly"`***